# Query to select a row based on a list of summary values

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm wondering if there is a way to perform this resulting query in Microsoft Access (2010) without writing VBA code.

I have a data table like this (more fields, but only showing the ones that count):

```
Customer ID       City Name
1                 Chicago
2                 Chicago
3                 New York
4                 San Antonio
5                 Seattle
6                 Seattle
7                 Walbash
8                 Walbash
```

I want to only select one row with each City.  For example, I want to select either row 1 or 2 for Chicago.

Resulting Results would look similar to this

```
Customer ID       City Name
1                 Chicago
3                 New York
4                 San Antonio
etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
select *
from Table1 t1
where t1.CustomerID = (select min(t2.CustomerID) from table1 t2 where t1.CityName = t2.CityName)
order by t1.CustomerID
```

Comment: This worked for me.  However, it ran a long time.  So I split it into two different tasks.  The first task created a summary of the CITY list and a minimum CustomerID.  Then added a "selection field" column to my original table.  I then did an update the selection field based on the summary table (joining it on City and (min) CustomerID to CustomerID).  This worked great.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT First(Table1.CustomerID) AS FirstOfCustomerID, Table1.CityName
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.CityName;
```

Example of other options to using `First()` are `Min()`, `Max()`

Edit:

Create the above query then do a join with your original table to select the record.  I named the above query `Q1` and the original table is `Table1`

```
SELECT Q1.FirstOfCustomerID, Q1.CityName, Table1.Data
FROM Q1 INNER JOIN Table1 ON Q1.FirstOfCustomerID = Table1.CustomerID;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I understand how to do the grouping.  I just need to select one record from each group.  I could do that in one query or break it up and tag the first record of each group.

Comment: I don't think I understand.  You'll need to rephrase your original question to help me understand better because this does exactly what you want from what you described in your question

Comment: Ah I think I realize what you mean, you have other fields that are unique and want to select that record.  I have edited my answer.